# ClamAV Updates - Daily Versus Main

Tags: clamav

Have an offline system with ClamAV.  Receiving daily.cvd files.  Are main.cvd updates a function of the daily? (enough dailies causes a main.cvd to be created) Or are main.cvds produced on a set schedule?  Current main.cvd is dated 7 Jun 2017.